# not able to figure out why username and password not set

Tags: php

I am making a navigation bar with embedded input form for login but the values of username and password are not getting set on clicking of login button .I am  stuck in this and i am not able to figure out why this is happening?

```
<div class="navbar-fixed">
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper black darken-2 z-depth-4 navbar-fixed">
        <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">&nbsp&nbsp $~ CodersArena</a>
        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down " >

            <?php
            include('includes/bootstrap.php');
            $con = dbConnect();
            if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
                $username =$_POST['username'];
                $password = $_POST['password'];
                $sql = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='" . $username . "' AND password='" . $password . "'";

                $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);


                if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                    echo"success";
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    echo '<li>
                    <span class="white-text white">';
                    echo  $_SESSION['username'];
                    echo '</span>
                </li>';

                }
            }
            else
        {

            if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

                echo '
            <form action="index.php"  method="POST" >
                <li style="padding: 20px auto; margin-right:10px ">
                    <input id="username" type="text" class="validate" style="height:30px" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Username">
                </li>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                <li style="padding: 20px auto; margin-right:10px "> 
                    <input id="password" type="text" style="height:30px" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password">
                </li>
                    <button style="padding: 20px auto; margin:10px " type="submit" class="btn-flat indigo darken-1 white-text right">Login</button>
            </form>';

            }
        }
            ?>

        </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: Where do you define `$username`? You are assigning its value to the `$_SESSION` array but I don't see you defining it

Comment: @LelioFaieta `$username =$_POST['username'];` is 6 code lines above `$_SESSION['username'] = $username;`

Comment: @IMSoP yes my mistake. Didn't notice

Comment: please note that you are open for SQL injections. Also you are not protecting your password. I hope this login method is also for learning purposes

Comment: @LelioFaieta I am just learning right now sir,if u can provide me reference for protecting password ,it would be really helpful...

Comment: have a look at password_hash on php.net. this can be a good starting point. Also look for prepared statements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `<input>`s are missing `name="username"` and `name="password"` attributes that will go into the POST request.
Any input without a `name` will not be included in the form submission.